# Three else-if statements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compiler-errors

Hi I am trying to have 4 buttons and each of them have different alerts when pressed. I am running into an issue, I had 3 buttons and I decided to add a "Rate My App" Button but now it isnt' working, please help me. (By the way the error is *Expexted Exspression*)(Org.=Organization (Fixed in App), Email- Real email in app,

```
#define TAG_Band 1
#define TAG_DEV 2
#define TAG_EDEV 3
#define TAG_RATE 4

@interface Org.ContactInfo () <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@end

@implementation Org.ContactInfo:UIViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Contacts";

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
-(IBAction)ContactBand:(id)sender;{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contact the Band" message:@"Contact the Org. or go to their website!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Visit the Org. Website",@"E-Mail The Org. President", @"E-Mail The Org. Treasurer",  nil];
    alert.tag = TAG_Band;
    [alert show];
}
-(IBAction)ContactDev:(id)sender;{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contact Me" message:@"Contact Me on Features you would like me to consider! I will do my Best to look at all of the Suggestions!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Visit My Website",@"E-Mail Me!",  nil];
    alert.tag = TAG_DEV;
    [alert show];
}
-(IBAction)RateMyApp:(id)sender;{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Rate My App" message:@"When Your Reviewing my App, Please remember that this app was at no cost to the Mighty Mustang Band." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Not Right Now" otherButtonTitles:@"Rate My App!!",  nil];
    alert.tag = TAG_RATE;
    [alert show];


}
-(IBAction)AppInfo:(id)sender;{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Version 1.0" message:@"More Updates Coming Soon. Please Feel Free to E-Mail me on features that you would like me to consider" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Not Right Now" otherButtonTitles:@"Email-Me",  nil];
    alert.tag = TAG_EDEV;
    [alert show];
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (alertView.tag == TAG_Band){


        if (buttonIndex==1){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://URL.org"]];

        }
        else if (buttonIndex==2){
            //Subject
            NSString *emailTitle = @"";
            //Recipients
            NSString *emailBody=@"Org. President";
            NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Person@Org.org"];

            MFMailComposeViewController *mc=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
            [mc setSubject:emailBody];
            [mc setToRecipients:toRecipients];

            [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

        }
        else if (buttonIndex==3){
            //Subject
            NSString *emailTitle = @"";
            //Recipients
            NSString *emailBody=@"Org. Treasurer, ";
            NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Person@Org.org"];

            MFMailComposeViewController *mc=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
            [mc setSubject:emailBody];
            [mc setToRecipients:toRecipients];

            [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

        }
    }
    else if (alertView.tag == TAG_DEV){
        if (buttonIndex==1){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stepheniosdeveloper.wordpress.com"]];

        }
        else if (buttonIndex==2){
            NSString *emailTitle = @"";
            //Recipients
            NSString *emailBody=@"";
            NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Email@gmail.com"];

            MFMailComposeViewController *mc=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
            [mc setSubject:emailBody];
            [mc setToRecipients:toRecipients];

            [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

        }
    }
    else if (alertView.tag == TAG_EDEV);{
        if (buttonIndex==1){
            NSString *emailTitle = @"";
            //Recipients
            NSString *emailBody=@"";
            NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Email@gmail.com"];

            MFMailComposeViewController *mc=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
            [mc setSubject:emailBody];
            [mc setToRecipients:toRecipients];

            [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

        }
    }
    else if (alertView.tag == TAG_RATE);{         //Expected Expression
        if (buttonIndex==1){
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/Org/id607257427?ls=1&mt=8"]];
        }
    }
}
```

It worked Before I added the last on (TAG_RATE) but now I don't understand why it isn't working anymore. Please Help.

Comment: Do you have something against `switch` statements?

Comment: can you help me with my code and format it with a switch statement, I thought about it, but i Couldnt figure out how to use it with my alerts and alert button actions. Please Format my code to where that work.

Answer (score 3):

There is a typo in your code: you have extra `;` after the last two `else if` conditions:

```
    else if (alertView.tag == TAG_EDEV)/*;*/{  // extra `;`
            //...
    }
    else if (alertView.tag == TAG_RATE)/*;*/{   // extra `;`       //Expected Expression
            // ...
    }
```

Comment: now when i hit the button connected to the EDEV Tag, it opens the link that the RATE Button is connected to. and when i get back to the app the email view is up for the EDEV tag

Comment: That fixed it, There was actually a messup really deep in their as well as those mistakes

Comment: Actually I have another question. I have  made the app profile on itunes connect and if you have done that before, you know that there is a button for viewing link in App store. Now I have not submitted the actual binary(So it says "Not currently availiable in US Store"), but it is waiting for upload. When The app is submitted and if it is accepted, Does the URL change, I need to know this for the Rate My App Tag.

Comment: you need to use breakpoint to see which line of code is executed. because `buttonIndex` can be not the one you expected. i always prefer to use button title instead